# CyberPanel installation problem to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: software-installation

Getting error.

```
Can't install Cyberpanel with LiteSpeed Enterprise to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

CyberPanel Installer v2.03

E: Unable to locate package nghttp2
E: Unable to locate package idn2
E: Unable to locate package virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `universe` repository, because `nghttp2`, `idn2` and `virtualenv` are available from `universe`.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Comment: getting another error >> sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

root@tek:~# sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: @land99 see my update